# Appending floats to a variable without performing arithmetics in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Working on a challenge to generate a random 3 digit number, then evaluate that number against a users inputted number and pay them according to different parameters met. I am Generating the number by creating 3 single float variables and appending them into a 4th variable. The current issue I run into has to do with appending versus performing the arithmetic when trying to only append all digits into a new variable. I can append the users input into a new 3 digit number within a new variable just fine, but when trying to take the 3 generated numbers, it simply adds the 3. Any idea why it behaves like this and how I can move forward? code:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
//prompt the user for a 3 digit number 
var user1  = readlineSync.question('Enter First Number: ');
var user2  = readlineSync.question('Enter Second Number: ');
var user3  = readlineSync.question('Enter Third Number: ');
var user4 = user1 + user2 + user3;
console.log("Your Number Is:" + user4);
//generate a lottery number: 3 digits long
var users1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var users2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var users3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var users4 = users1 + users2 + users3;
console.log("Your Number Is:" + users4)

//console.log("Winning Numbers Are:" + digit1 + digit2 + digit3)
//check users input against generated number
//if all nums match in order: print $10k
//if all nums match out of order: print $3k
//if one digit matches: print $1k
```

Terminal Output after running:

~/Desktop/nodeStuff$ node Program2-2.js
Enter First Number: 1

Enter Second Number: 2

Enter Third Number: 3

Your Number Is:123

Your Number Is:21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variables `users1`, `users2` and `users3` all have `integer` data. When you use `+` in javascript, if either of the values you are trying to append are `string` type, it just gets concatenated. If all the values are numbers, it gets summed.

You need to convert these three values to `string` type.

```js
var users1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
var users2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
var users3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
```

Notice the `toString` at the end of each line.